# Mongoose .save fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I learning node.js & mongoDB & mongoose, from maybe a week or 2. The problem I have right now is, I'm trying to save to db via mongoose *.save()*, but it doesn't work as expected. I'm watching a tutorial, and it's 3 days old, so should be up to date, but I'm getting strange error.

> mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated” error when testing [duplicate]

I read, here on stackoverflow that I can just add:

> mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

It will work, but the code doesn't even go to the .save function, and don't trow an error. I'm not sure where the problem is.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
let connectionString = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mongo2';

mongoose.createConnection(connectionString, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    let Student = mongoose.model('Student', {
        firstName: {type: String, required: true},
        lastName: {type: String, required: true},
        age: {type: Number},
        facultyNumber: {type: String, unique: true}
    });

    let me = new Student({
        firstName: 'Who',
        lastName: 'amI',
        age: 20,
        facultyNumber: '9374823104'
    });

    me.save().then((info) => {
        console.log(info);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

**Edit:** The result is: Getting the DB created, the collection too, but not the object. Everything is empty.

Comment: You are not actually connected. createConnection does not actually establish the connection. Instead you should really `mongoose.connect(connectionstring,{ useMongoClient: true }),then( () => { /* code that does stuff */ })` or better yet use `async/await` and `await mongoose.connect(connectionstring, { useMongoClient: true });`. Also in the modern world `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise` will generally do unless you specifically "want" bluebird. You need to plugin the promises, so you really should learn how to use them.

Comment: How I am not connected if I create collection? @NeilLunn

Comment: Beause `createConnection` just "creates". It does not open. Where are you reading your instructions from? All official sources will tell you what to correctly do.

Comment: Local academy video clip. The "mongoose.connect(connectionString, {
    useMongoClient: true
}).then(() => {" worked out. I think I'm paying them too much...

Comment: Ugh! Sorry, but not the first time someone has pointed to paid subsrcription training that's pretty subpar. Always read the official documentation. Lots of detail on [connections](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html). You might also pick up a few things generally browsing answers in the mongoose tag on here as well. Note also that none of that schema definition really should be "inside" the connection and is perfectly fine ( as well as you **should** ) to define before you connect. It's only actual interaction ( `.save()`, `.find()` etc ) that actually needs the connection established.

Comment: @NeilLunn this is actually interesting. And ye, this academy took 1 lecture for mongodb and mongoose (2 hours total), and 3 more for express.js. The course itself is called Express.js Developer...

Answer (score 0):

Very likely the problem is that your model does not have a schema attached.

```
const { Schema } = require('mongoose');
const StudentSchema = new Schema({
        firstName: {type: String, required: true},
        lastName: {type: String, required: true},
        age: {type: Number},
        facultyNumber: {type: String, unique: true}
    }};

let Student = mongoose.model('Student', StudentSchema);
```